# Error while doing conferencing in Twilio

Tags: php, android, twilio, conferencing

I am developing an application for doing voice calls via `Twilio API`
But it disconnects after first call.

Here is my code:

`my index.php`

```
<?php
$serverroot=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/twilioapi/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php';
require($serverroot); 
$version = "2010-04-01"; 
 $num= '+1 218-461-4418';
 $num1= '+91$$$$$$$$$$$';
 $num2= '+91$$$$$$$$$$$';
 $num3= '+91$$$$$$$$$$$';  

$account_sid = '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'; 
$auth_token = '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'; 
$client = new TwilioRestClient($account_sid, $auth_token); 

  $participants = array($num1, $num2, $num3);

  // Go through the participants array and call each person.
  foreach ($participants as $particpant)
  {
    $vars = array(
      'From' => $num,
      'To' => $participant,
      'Url' => 'http://my_url.com/twilioapi/mytest2.xml');

    echo $response = $client->request("/$version/Accounts/$account_sid/Calls", "GET", $vars);
  }

//echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

---

`xml file`

```
<Response>
    <Say>Joining a conference room</Say>
       <Dial>
         <Conference>MyRoom</Conference>
       </Dial>
</Response>
```

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure why your code would make one call and then disconnect. I can tell you one thing I'd do differently though, which might help.

Instead of making the call to the API using a `TwilioRestClient` object like you did:

```
// Set up $client
$client = new TwilioRestClient($account_sid, $auth_token); 
// Make request (using $vars from loop)
$client->request("/$version/Accounts/$account_sid/Calls", "GET", $vars);
```

You can actually require the `Services_Twilio` class and make calls much easier with it:

```
// set up $client
$client = new Sevices_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);

// set up participants then...

foreach ($participants as $particpant) {
  echo $response = $client->account->calls->create(
    $num,          // The from number
    $participant,  // The to number
    'http://my_url.com/twilioapi/mytest2.xml'
  );
```

}

One other thing that occurs to me. The call to the Calls endpoint to create a call should be a `POST` not a `GET`. Perhaps that is why it is failing. Using the `Services_Twilio` object should help with that though.

Take a look at the [documentation on creating calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-request) or let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.... Your code example didn't worked but your idea about the calls did..... It worked like a charm. :-)